# How to include Ruby class extensions from other modules?

Tags: ruby, class, module, include

I want to make class extensions available to other modules/classes/files. For example:

```
module UsefulStuff
  class Object
    def blank?
      respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
    end
  end
end
```

in other class/module/file:

```
if string.blank? ...
```

What and how do I include/load/require/... to make this work?

Comment: Do you want to add that `blank?` method to all objects?

Comment: In the case of blank?, yes, it should work for all classes that have an empty? method (String, Array, Hash).  However, more generally, my question is, when I extend a Class how do I include it in other files so that objects in those other files will see the extension?  Could you provide an example where the class extension is in one file, and the use of it is in another file (which might be a module, a class, or just a script with main code).

Comment: See Nucc's answer, it is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a module instead of a class:

```
module UsefulStuff
  module Blank
    def blank?
      respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
    end
  end
end
```

and you can include it in String class:

```
class String
  include UsefulStuff::Blank
end
```

or if you want it to be global for objects:

```
class Object
  include UsefulStuff::Blank
end
```